# Acronym generator in javascript. It only grabs the first letter of the first word, but the not the other words

Tags: javascript

Am I missing something in my code? It seems to only grab the first letter, and the while loop, doesn't go onto the next word. So what could I be missing?

```
function acr(s){
    var words, acronym, nextWord;

    words = s.split();
    acronym= "";
    index = 0
    while (index<words.length) {
            nextWord = words[index];
            acronym = acronym + nextWord.charAt(0);
            index = index + 1 ;
    }
    return acronym
}
```

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but just an aside: be sure to always declare all variables with `var` or they'll have global scope. Your `index` variable will be global and thus potentially overwrite an existing global - I'm assuming you don't really mean to do that. (Also, what have you got against `for` loops?)

Comment: Out of curiosity, was your problem solved? If so please consider asking whichever answer helped you most, and up-voting those you found useful. Otherwise please consider editing your question in order that we can help you further. :)

Answer (score 6):

If you only care about IE9+ then the answer can be made shorter:

```js
function acronym(text) {
  return text
    .split(/\s/)
    .reduce(function(accumulator, word) {
      return accumulator + word.charAt(0);
    }, '');
}

console.log(acronym('three letter acronym'));
```

If you can use arrow functions then it can be made shorter still:

```js
function acronym(text) {
  return text
    .split(/\s/)
    .reduce((accumulator, word) => accumulator + word.charAt(0), '');
}

console.log(acronym('three letter acronym'));
```

Answer (score 3):

Add the separator to the `split`:

```
function acr(s){
    var words, acronym, nextWord;

    words = s.split(' ');
    acronym= "";
    index = 0
    while (index<words.length) {
            nextWord = words[index];
            acronym = acronym + nextWord.charAt(0);
            index = index + 1 ;
    }
    return acronym
}
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/P6JXE/);

Revised the above to make it a little more demonstrative, and also interactive: [JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/P6JXE/1/).

---

**Edited** to add references and explanation:

Because no separator was supplied the string remains un-split; therefore the `while` was operating correctly (as `words.length` is equal to `1`), and so returns only the first letter of the string:

> [Separator] specifies the character to use for separating the string. The separator is treated as a string or a regular expression. If separator is omitted, the array returned contains one element consisting of the entire string.

Reference:

- [`split()`, at MDC Docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)

Answer (score 2):

You forgot to split on whitespace:

```
words = s.split(/\s/);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can have this in even lesser code. Try this

```
s.match(/\b(\w)/g).join("").toUpperCase()
```